# How to compare load time for a website in different internet speeds ( 3G fast, 3G slow and 4 G) with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to check the load and response time of a website using Jmeter and compare the results for 3g slow, 3G fast and 4G internet speeds, to see what impact it creates on the laod and response time of the site

Answer (score 0):

There are [special JMeter properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient_common_properties) to control the bandwidth:

- `httpclient.socket.http.cps` - Set characters per second to a value greater then zero to emulate slow connections.
- `httpclient.socket.https.cps` - Same as before but for https

so if you add the next lines to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps=2688000
httpclient.socket.https.cps=2688000
```

on next JMeter restart the outgoing and incoming traffic speed will be limited to 3G network maximum bandwidth.

More information: [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: hi Dimitri, thankyou for the response .  so we can check load / response time with a speed one at a time ? i mean is there a way to execute same tests with 3G and 4 G simultaneously  and get the result

Comment: For single JMeter instance - no, but if you go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) you can configure one slave to throttle to 3G connection speed and another slave to 4G.